# CultureInfo.InvariantCulture и с чем его едят

Tags: c#, дата

Здравствуйте, уважаемые!

Возник такой вопрос, как использовать CultureInfo.InvariantCulture при конверте строк в дату и в случае с денежными величинами в double. С датами вроде всё понятно. Как я понимаю CultureInfo.InvariantCulture говорит о том, что формат в полученной строке соответствует формату, указанному в языковых настройках твоего компьютера. С датой я в этом убедился. Однако в случае с денежной величиной возникает вопрос, почему вот это:

```
double.Parse("2135.45", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

нормально конвертится и не вызывает исключений. Ведь денежный формат России указывается через запятую.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не правильно понимаете. Как сказано [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.90).aspx), это как раз не зависимая от языка локаль.

Comment: То что там написано, я уже прочитал. А Вы как сами понимаете это?
Что значит независимая? Если я укажу дату в японском формате, как CLR поймёт в каком формате я указал? Волшебный CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ей в этом не поможет. 
p.s. Дабы закрепить теорию практиктой, я всё проверил. И моё понимание основывается именно на практике.

Comment: `Свойство InvariantCulture получает экземпляр инвариантного языка и региональных параметров. Он связан с английским языком, но не связан ни с какой страной или регионом.`

это означает что функции работающие с локалью забивают на локаль системы, и парсят всё из дефолтовых настроек английского языка. Если вы укажете дату в японском формате он не поймёт, и будет её парсить как английскую.

Comment: Вот теперь всё понял! Просто это влияние англо-слэнга мешает русскому мозгу понимать такие слова как инвариантный)
@Чад, то есть по сути CultureInfo.InvariantCulture заменяет равнозначно CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US") ??
Или приведите пожалуйста пример, если я до конца неправильно понял

Comment: Ну мне кажется да, хотя там наверное не совсем "en-US", думаю там есть некоторые отличия от "en-US", скорее всего в рамках специфики именно US(т.е. специфики US нету). Это надо просто посмотреть свойство локали. Но суть верна.